# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NotificationCompatBuilder

Tags: android, notifications

It's the first time I see this crash during the notification building:
(Android 7.0 with SM-J330FN device)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field ??Ĳǹ8zL՗??uڭȹȑ쪿:7ۀ⭮Ս݇zM(ad)ғ勼Ǣы~ǰ?腚?sȹ掵>?aѥ0??+ڙǐI'䲈Z.ύiscȠսTļ絛??6ݿ
rɕ of type Z in class Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder' appears in base.apk)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatBuilder.<init>(NotificationCompatBuilder.java:123)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:1484)
```

My gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0.09"

        minSdkVersion 19 // Min SDK supported by this app (= KITKAT)
        targetSdkVersion 27 // SDK dedicated for this app
```

Do you have an idea to investigate?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: post your app level gradle please !!

Comment: @SantanuSur I've updated my post, thank you very much

Comment: @anthony post the full `build.gradle`